# Get my IP address and convert it into bytes using C++

Tags: c++, networking, cross-platform, byte, ip-address

What is the best way to get your IP address and then convert it into bytes using C++? I need something cross-platform. I found a lot but I do not know what is the best technique.

Comment: You mean get the ip-address (ipv4 I am assuming) of the local machine on which the code is running?

Comment: What if there is more than one IP address ? Or none ?

Comment: at the moment I do not want to give too much importance to this because the machine
will certainly have an ip address .. however, I suggest that always take
the first, eg the one on eth0

Answer (score 4):

You can use gethostname followed by gethostbyname to get your local interface internal IP.

You can try this code:

```
struct IPv4
{
  unsigned char b1, b2, b3, b4;
};

bool getMyIP(IPv4 & myIP)
{
  char szBuffer[1024];

  #ifdef WIN32
  WSADATA wsaData;
  WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 0);
  if(::WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData) != 0)
    return false;
  #endif


  if(gethostname(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
  {
    #ifdef WIN32
    WSACleanup();
    #endif
    return false;
  }

  struct hostent *host = gethostbyname(szBuffer);
  if(host == NULL)
  {
    #ifdef WIN32
    WSACleanup();
    #endif
    return false;
  }

  //Obtain the computer's IP
  myIP.b1 = ((struct in_addr *)(host->h_addr))->S_un.S_un_b.s_b1;
  myIP.b2 = ((struct in_addr *)(host->h_addr))->S_un.S_un_b.s_b2;
  myIP.b3 = ((struct in_addr *)(host->h_addr))->S_un.S_un_b.s_b3;
  myIP.b4 = ((struct in_addr *)(host->h_addr))->S_un.S_un_b.s_b4;

  #ifdef WIN32
  WSACleanup();
  #endif
  return true;
}
```

Use  htonl, htons, ntohl, ntohs functions to convert between network and local byte orders.

Comment: I plan to get my ipaddress (ipv4), I plan to convert this into bytes and then i put these bytes in a message to be sent in multicast

Comment: Winsock is also not cross-platform.

Comment: @Paul: This is BSD sockets.  All the winsock stuff is surrounded by `#if`.

Comment: @Ben: it is *now* - comments and down-vote removed since the answer has now been improved.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to do this in C++, because C++ also runs on systems which have no network.

Each operating system has a different way to query local interface addresses.  The most "portable" thing you can hope to find is a library that provides a single consistent interface with underlying implementations corresponding to all major operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

As Ben stated, you could use a *non-standard* library that has implementations for many OSs.
By no means is boost the silver bullet, but the boost asio library is a really useful, well-designed, portable networking library with implementations for many operating systems. Specifically asio provides the [ip::host_name](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__host_name.html) method.

Answer (score 0):

Two methods you can use to convert an IP to a string are inet_ntoa (IPv4 only) or getnameinfo with the flag NI_NUMERICHOST (IPv4 and IPv6).